# Flask - Why bcrypt returns false ?

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

My models file is like this

```
from app import db, b_crypt


class Base(db.Model):

    __abstract__  = True

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime,  default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime,  default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())


class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'auth_user'

    # User Name
    name = db.Column(db.String(128),  nullable=False)

    # Identification Data: email & password
    email = db.Column(db.String(128),  nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String,  nullable=False)

    # Authorisation Data: role & status
    role = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)

    # New instance instantiation procedure
    def __init__(self, name, email, password, role, status):

        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = b_crypt.generate_password_hash(password)
        self.role = role
        self.status = status

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.name
```

my blueprinted view function

```
from app.blueprints.authentication.models import User

# Import tools
from app.blueprints.tools.db import is_authenticated, is_registered, add_user_to_database
    @auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
    def login():
        email = request.form['eml']
        password = request.form['pwd']
        if is_registered(email):
            if is_authenticated(email, password):
                session['logged_in'] = True
                session['user'] = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first().username
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                flash("Wrong Credentials")
                return render_template('auth/auth.html')
        else:
            flash("You are not registered!")
            return render_template('auth/auth.html')
```

and my tools.db is like this, this file is basically functions that i want to keep seperate from the main app and maintain a modular app. The functions does what they say at the name.

```
from app.blueprints.authentication.models import User
from app import db, b_crypt


def is_registered(email):
    return User.query.filter_by(email=email).first() is not None


def is_authenticated(email, password):
    return b_crypt.check_password_hash(User.query.filter_by(email=email).first().password, password)


def add_user_to_database(username, password, email, role, status):
    try:
        user = User(
            name=username,
            password=b_crypt.generate_password_hash(password),
            email=email,
            role=role,
            status=False
        )
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as manager_rugby:
        print manager_rugby.message
        db.session.rollback()
```

When i log in , is_authenticated always return false ! why? please help i really have no idea why it doesn't work. It gets 2 strings and returns a boolean , but the password is correct i dont know whats wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the hashes of the password? I think you need to change your `__init__` method in the `User` model. Remove this line from there:

```
self.password = b_crypt.generate_password_hash(password)
```

Set the hashed password just before you save the model. I suspect that you hash your password twice. This is why it returns false everytime.

Comment: Thank you so much!! i was hashing a hash hahahaha +rep